# PHP CloudFlare Login

Tags: php, curl, authentication, cloud, flare

I've tried countless times to make a PHP script that auto logins to my CloudFlare account only with some success. I did make a script that logins but does not show the contents of page after the login. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please provide the code that is not working so that people can help identify what is wrong. You can find tips on how to write a good questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just for your information: there is a CloudFare API: https://api.cloudflare.com/ Use it!

Answer (score 0):

As CloudFlare has CSRF protection (as you would expect!) you cannot merely just send a post request to their login endpoint.

I have done this by means of a Chrome of a extension. Essentially I wrote a bit of Javascript that would get from a PHP script, the username and password to pass into CloudFlare from a PHP script after doing an AJA request. It then populates the field and submits the request (checking the referrer isn't login endpoint, preventing an infinite loop if the login details are wrong).

I hope this is useful.